# using curl through a proxy with php

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Any idea where my code is going wrong...I am trying to connect through a proxy with the curl function in php...I assuming the proxy worked bc I tried a few from this list http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/search-234921 but cant seem to get any to function correctly...

Thoughts?

```
function my_fetch($url,$user_agent='Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)')
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '75.74.244.122:1523');
$data = curl_exec();
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest trying first with your own proxy. This way you could have a look at the proxy logs to get additional information about what is really happening.

Comment: Have a look at squid [ http://www.squid-cache.org ]. It is a free open source proxy. There you will find the documentation for installation and management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like the proxy you are using is working:

```
jasonfunk@jasonfunk-laptop:$ telnet 75.74.244.122 1523
Trying 75.74.244.122...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try multiple proxy by using random one by one using this script

Get random proxy

```
  function get_random_proxy(){
  srand ((double)microtime()*1000000);
  $f_contents = file ("proxy.txt");
  $line = $f_contents[array_rand ($f_contents)];
  return $line;
  }
```

call curl function using one proxy randomly

```
function get_curl_proxy($url){

$proxy_ip = get_random_proxy();
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.233.0 Safari/532.4";
$referer = "http://www.google.com/";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}
```

For further reference see this
http://altafphp.blogspot.in/2012/06/using-proxies-with-curl-in-php.html